# Are the Iris's the same person?

Tags: atelier

In the Atelier Iris series, all 3 games have character called Iris.

In *Atelier Iris: Eternal Mana* and *Atelier Iris 2: The Azoth of Destiny*, they both have Iris Blanchimont. In the first game, she is a great Alchemist who practices the many teachings of  (with the exception of Mull) and she befriended the Mana.

> She, however, passed away long before the start of the game from fighting Amalgam, leaving only her final creation Lita and the materials and formula to create the Ruby Prism

This is Iris in the first game:

[image]

In the second game, she appears as a small child who is taken in by Viese Blanchimont as her sister (though one could speculate that Viese and Felt one day married and adopted Iris as their daughter).

> Later, we learn that she has the reincarnated powers of Lilith, the Creation Mana, who looks a lot like her, which explains her talents in alchemy.

Also in Belkhyde, there are placed like the Tower of Marcus and the Cleft of Nelva

> And at the end, Lilith's power releases Mana throughout Belkhyde which makes Alchemy possible again.

This is Iris in the second game:

[image]

I just started playing *Atelier Iris 3: Grand Phantasm* and found out the Iris in this game is named *Iris Fortner*. It's mentioned she was raised by a family of Alchemists. However, when she talks to Yach about how she made the Heal Jars for the quest, he doesn't believe her and Edge indicates that Alchemists are rare (kinda like what was mentioned in the first game with Klein). Furthermore, it seems no one know about Mana and the world seems disjointed with other worlds called Afterworlds.

This is Iris Fortner:

[image]

They all look similar, and the first 2 games hint at a direct connection (with Iris's last name and how she would learn Alchemy). Is Iris Fortner the same as Iris Blanchimont (being a younger version of her from Atelier Iris 1)?

If that is not the case, is there a deeper connection to her and the game's title? Apart from her looking like the previous Iris, being an Alchemist and being a main character from the very start.

Comment: I've never played these games (just Eternal Mana, where she doesn't appear, and the vaguely similar Ar Tonelico), but could it be sort of like Link in the Zelda series? A bunch of "spiritual successors" appearing across time? Or possibly even descendants of the original Iris?

Comment: @Torisuda the Arland Atelier subseries are connected together story wise and aren't all that far apart as we see Rorona then Totori get older in later games and there is no mention of Iris or Mana in them so i'm assuming Atelier Iris 3 is the last time we see "Iris".

Comment: (cont.) descendant/spiritual successor might be Iris Fortner's relation with Iris Blanchimont but i don't have time frames of when the games were set and if Iris Fortner is Iris Blanchimont's decendent than Iris Blanchimont is truly a genius since that means Lita can have children, but the 2 Iris Blanchimont i think are the same given Eden's location in relation to where Avenberry is with the other identically named locations (Tower of Marcus, the Cleft of Nelva) and what i mentioned about Young Iris Blanchimont. ofcause i am looking for sources to prove a connection if any

Answer (score -1):

the Iris from Eternal Mana and Azoth of Destiny are the same, set at different points in the timeline. Grand Phantasm was originally supposed to take place during Iris Blanchemont's alchemy career with the main antagonist and the young elder witch from the first game as her teammates, however the storyline was scrapped and altered, resulting in the seperation. so Iris Fortner is not Iris Blanchemont. but Eternal Mana Iris and Azoth of Destiny young Iris are one and the same.